# Use data from Json to go to page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a landing page with json. I am trying to have it so when someone clicks it goes to a page from the json file. So far I have this:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        var Link = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("Link1").innerHTML = Link.title;
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "link.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
      
function click1(){ 
    window.location.href = Link.link;
}
```

And when I click on it it gives me (from console):

> (index):22 Uncaught ReferenceError: Link is not defined at click1 ((index):22) at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):8)

Comment: `Link` is local to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`, so you can't reference it from `click1`. Why not put the entire XMLHttpRequest routine in the click function body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON content has properties `title` and `link`, and that your `click1` handler has been properly registered, you should be able to combine what you have into something like this:

```
function click1() { 
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var Link = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("Link1").innerHTML = Link.title;
      window.location.href = Link.link;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "link.json", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Note that setting the `innerHTML` of an element before `window.location.href = Link.link;` is somewhat pointless because updating `window.location` will cause a new page to load.

Comment: That works. I have a wait command so that the link is visible for a couple secods before refreshing